# Big SQL SELECT performance difference when using <= against using < on a DATETIME column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the following table:

```
desc exchange_rates;
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| time             | datetime       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| base_currency    | varchar(3)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| counter_currency | varchar(3)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| rate             | decimal(32,16) | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have added indexes on `time`, `base_currency` and `counter_currency`, as well as a composite index on (time, base_currency, counter_currency), but I'm seeing a big performance difference when I perform a `SELECT` using `<=` against using `<`.

The first `SELECT` is:

```
ExchangeRate Load (95.5ms)   
SELECT * FROM `exchange_rates` WHERE (time <= '2009-12-30 14:42:02' and base_currency = 'GBP' and counter_currency = 'USD') LIMIT 1
```

As you can see this is taking 95ms.

If I change the query such that I compare time using `<` rather than `<=` I see this:

```
ExchangeRate Load (0.8ms)   
SELECT * FROM `exchange_rates` WHERE (time < '2009-12-30 14:42:02' and base_currency = 'GBP' and counter_currency = 'USD') LIMIT 1
```

Now it takes less than 1 millisecond, which sounds right to me.  Is there a rational explanation for this behaviour?

The output from `EXPLAIN` provides further details, but I'm not 100% sure how to intepret this:

```
-- Output from the first, slow, select
SIMPLE      | 5,5     | exchange_rates | 1  | index_exchange_rates_on_time,index_exchange_rates_on_base_currency,index_exchange_rates_on_counter_currency,time_and_currency | index_merge | Using intersect(index_exchange_rates_on_counter_currency,index_exchange_rates_on_base_currency); Using where | 813  |     | index_exchange_rates_on_counter_currency,index_exchange_rates_on_base_currency

-- Output from the second, fast, select
SIMPLE      | 5       | exchange_rates | 1  | index_exchange_rates_on_time,index_exchange_rates_on_base_currency,index_exchange_rates_on_counter_currency,time_and_currency | ref  | Using where | 4988 | const | index_exchange_rates_on_counter_currency
```

(Note: I'm producing these queries through `ActiveRecord` (in a Rails app) but these are ultimately the queries which are being executed)

Comment: What does PROCEDURE ANALYSE() say? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/procedure-analyse.html

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `MySQL` tries to combine results from all indexes. It fetches all records from both indexes and joins them on the value of the row pointer (table offset in `MyISAM`, `PRIMARY KEY` in `InnoDB`).

In the second case, it just uses a single index, which, considering `LIMIT 1`, is the best decision.

You need to create a composite index on `(base_currency, counter_currency, time)` (in this order) for this query to work as fast as possible.

The engine will use the index for filtering on the leading columns `(base_currency, counter_currency)` and for ordering on the trailing column `(time)`.

It also seems you want to add something like `ORDER BY time DESC` to your query to get the last exchange rate.

In general, any `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` should ring the bell.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I have actually already added a composite index on  (time, base_currency, counter_currency).

Comment: `@Olly`: the columns go in the wrong order. The order matters.

Comment: The only remaining point is, why on earth is the query planner outputting different plans when the <= or < on the time column is insignificant for the index usage. Strange stuff.

Comment: `@Michael`: I've never seen it myself (and cannot reproduce it for now), but seems that most records are exactly within the timestamp passed as a parameter and `@OP` just hit the tipping point where `MySQL` prefers one plan over the other. Anyway, one needs access to actual data to tell exactly.

Comment: `@Quassnoi`: Regarding the order, I thought the composite index had to reflect the order in which the fields appear in the WHERE clause? In my case, time comes first, then base_currency, then counter_currency, hence I created the index using (time, base_currency, counter_currency).  Is this not correct?

Comment: `@Olly`: no, this is not correct. With `AND`, the order in the `WHERE` clause does not matter. An index orders the records lexicographically (first on `base_currency`, second on `counter_currency`, finally on `time`). With your `base_currency` and `counter_currency` equifiltered and `time` range filtered, the index can give a single continuous range or records: from `('GBP', 'USD', -INF)` to `('GBP', 'USD', NOW())`. See here for more detailed explanation on composite indexes: http://explainextended.com/2009/05/09/creating-indexes/

Comment: It's the same as with a dictionary. Say, you need the first letter to be `A`, second letter to be `S` and the third letter to be less than `K`. This means all words from `'AS'` to `'ASK'` which are on one or two pages and you can easily read them through. But if you ask for the second and third letter to be `AP` and the first letter to be more than `'A'`, you'll need to read trough the whole dictionary from `'BAP*'` to `'ZAP*'`.